# Facebook Pixel on web site using DNN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, dotnetnuke

I am trying to implement the Facebook pixel into a site built on the DNN platform.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add it to the bottom of your Skin by opening it in a Text Editor and paste the code at the bottom. The skin files are either located in  `/Portals/_default/Skins/{SkinName}` or `/Portals/{PortalID}/Skins/{SkinName}`. In there are files with the `.ascx` extension, that are the ones you need to edit.

You can also add a `Text/HTML` module to the page, and then display that module on every page. You can do this in Module Settings > Advanced Settings > CheckBox: Display module on all pages.

Comment: Okay I found the default skin file to upload the base facebook pixel code snippet but my real issue is custom events.  Such as 'view content' add to cart' etc. My issue currently is I cant load these custom events on specific pages or groups of pages such as www.whateveryouwantthisurltobe.com/products and every page including this URL

Comment: Unless the webshop module has a build-in functionality for that, you're gonna have to build one yourself. But even with custom events, as long as the correct skin is used the pixel will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to VDWWD's answer and OP's comment, I see two ways of going about adding custom events in specific places:

1. The tedious way:
   On each page, add a text/html module on the relevant pages, put the fb pixel javascript code inside it. You'll have to choose plain text mode in the text/html module, to make sure that the javascript code is not parsed out. Tedious, but it will work. If you don't want to use the text/html module, you can make multiple, renamed copies of your skin .ascx files, and assign a specific copy with a specific fb pixel snippet to each specific page in question.
2. The not so tedious way:
   If you know of a DNN module named XMod Pro, you can use their templates feature to easily add any code to any page. That code can be server side AND client side, which is what makes it great if you perhaps need the user's UserID and if you need a URL parameter of the page, or anything else that's server side and of use to you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm this does help alot.  I just started working for a company that has been using DNN for a while so some of the versions are pretty out of date. I have never really used DNN and I find it...horrible haha.  One of the bigger issues I'm having, is installing DNN Modules.  Would you have any recommendations on the best practice for that?

Comment: Also wouldn't making multiple copies of the same skin.ascx file be a bit dangerous?

Comment: Hmm it seems the DNN platform for this particular site doesn't have an install extension wizard -_-

Comment: What is version of your DNN instance that's missing an extension wizard? It _should_ always one AFAIK. Sadly, that's the usual DNN user experience roadmap: it starts with hating it...the good news is that the more you use it, the more you'll start to like it. Trust me!

Comment: It's an older versions but where would I even check that ?

Comment: You would go to host > host settings. If in doubt, check this: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/360/view/details/how-to-tell-what-version-of-dotnetnuke-you-are-on